# Using a HAVING clause in an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, having

This query

```
SELECT
FirstName, LastName, NCAAStats.AccountId, College_Translator.school_name, StatTypeId, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM NCAAstats
INNER JOIN College_Translator
ON College_Translator.AccountID = NCAAstats.AccountId
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, NCAAStats.AccountId, College_Translator.school_name, CalendarYear, StatTypeId
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
ORDER BY 'Count' DESC
```

Selects records that I would like to set an `ISValid` bit to `0`.

These records are records that appear twice in my database due to an input error.

I'm looking for something like:

```
UPDATE NCAAstats
SET IsValid = 0
WHERE (my select statement)
```

This is on MS SQL SERVER 2008

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can join to that subquery like so:

```
update n1 set
    isvalid = 0
from
    ncaastats n1
    inner join (
        SELECT
        FirstName, LastName, NCAAStats.AccountId, College_Translator.school_name, StatTypeId, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
        FROM NCAAstats
        INNER JOIN College_Translator
        ON College_Translator.AccountID = NCAAstats.AccountId
        GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, NCAAStats.AccountId, College_Translator.school_name, CalendarYear, StatTypeId
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1
    ) n2 on
        n1.accountid = n2.accountid
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server can do updates like:

```
UPDATE table SET col=vaue
FROM (
  SELECT ......
)
```

You should look here first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The above are good suggestions.... here's another easy way to do it :

```
update ncaastats set isvalid = 0
where accountId in (
    SELECT AccountId
    FROM NCAAstats
    INNER JOIN College_Translator
    ON College_Translator.AccountID = NCAAstats.AccountId
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, NCAAStats.AccountId, College_Translator.school_name, CalendarYear, StatTypeId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >1
)
```

** Forgive me if I messed up the columns name, but you get the idea.

Comment: For what it's worth, that will go really slowly, since the subquery will be executed against each row.

Comment: @Eric - I don't think it will.  What are you basing that on?

Comment: @JNK - You're correct--the `in` causes a semi join in SQL 2008. My fault--forgot the engine. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @Eric - no problem, just wanted to make sure you didn't know something I had missed :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE, and do what is basically a self join

```
;with NCAAstatsToUpdate(
    SELECT AccountId 
    FROM NCAAstats n
        INNER JOIN College_Translator ct
      ON ct.AccountID = n.AccountId 
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, n.AccountId, ct.school_name, 
         CalendarYear, StatTypeId 
    HAVING COUNT(*) >1 )
UPDATE NCAAstats 
SET IsValid=0
FROM NCAAstats n
inner join NCAAstatsToUpdate u
    on n.AccountId = u.AccountId
```

Or better yet, use the windowing functions.

```
;with NCStats as(
 Select distinct row_number() over (partition by FirstName, LastName, n.AccountId, ct.school_name, 
         CalendarYear, StatTypeId order by n.accountId) rw, n.*
 FROM NCAAstats n
        INNER JOIN College_Translator ct
      ON ct.AccountID = n.AccountId 
)
Update NCStats
Set IsValid=0
Where rw>1
```

Note that second does not update the "first" record to invalid, and that it assumes that there that there is a 1 to 1 relationship between NCAAstats and College_Translator.

Answer (score -1):

For SQL Server 17

```
UPDATE table SET col = val 
(SELECT cols FROM table .. )
```