# mySQL Update on having count grouped by

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT t1.shop_id, t1.cat_id, t1.detailtype_id, t1.exact_matching, COUNT(t3.part) AS AantalOnderdelen
FROM tbldetailspershop t1
LEFT JOIN tbltranslationscompound t2 ON t1.compound_group_id = t2.group_id AND t2.part_detailtype_id=825
LEFT JOIN tbltranslationscompound t3 ON t1.compound_group_id = t3.group_id
WHERE t1.detailtype_id=14519 AND t1.cat_id=11111 AND t1.exact_matching=0 #and t2.part_detailtype_id=825
GROUP BY t1.shop_id, t1.cat_id, t1.detailtype_id
HAVING COUNT(t3.part)=1
```

Now, this results in 3000 rows which have t1.exact_matching 0. See below for the output of the select query (just 1 row)

```
shop_id;cat_id;detailtype_id;exact_matching
6;11111;14519;0
```

Now I'd like to update the exact_matching column to 1 for all the rows returned by the select query from above. I can't figure out how to write the update statement though, as I want to make sure only these 3000 rows are affected which meet the having and where conditions from the above select query.

I got this now:

```
UPDATE tbldetailspershop SET exact_matching = 1
WHERE (shop_id, cat_id, detailtype_id) IN
(
SELECT t1.shop_id, t1.cat_id, t1.detailtype_id
FROM tbldetailspershop t1
LEFT JOIN tbltranslationscompound t2 ON t1.compound_group_id = t2.group_id AND t2.part_detailtype_id=825
LEFT JOIN tbltranslationscompound t3 ON t1.compound_group_id = t3.group_id
WHERE t1.detailtype_id=14519 AND t1.cat_id=11111 AND t1.exact_matching=0
GROUP BY t1.shop_id, t1.cat_id, t1.detailtype_id
HAVING COUNT(t3.part)=1
)
```

Comment: Well I just cant get my head around it... I've tried double subselects but I keep on getting stuck.. I've thought about using a temp table but I'd like to know how it is solved using just 1 update query

Comment: Your condition is on a group, so the affected rows of your desired update could be more than 3000.

Comment: @Simimmo yes thats correct, and thats the problem in running into writing my update query

Comment: I believe it would help a lot if you edited your question to show the structure of the tables, and also explain your query in plain English (i.e. what rows exactly are you trying to update?). Also, have you tried JOIN in  your update? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793914/using-a-having-clause-in-an-update-statement

Comment: Maybe you don't see but you can completely remove line `LEFT JOIN tbltranslationscompound t2 ...` it brings nothing to resultset. You don't take any data from that table, and since it is `LEFT JOIN` it can't work as a filter for main data table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
update shopdetails
set exact_matching = 1
where (shop_id, cat_id, detailtype_id, exact_matching) in
(
select t1.shop_id, t1.cat_id, t1.detailtype_id, t1.exact_matching from shopdetails t1
left join transcomp t2 on t1.compound_group_id = t2.group_id and t2.part_detailtype_id=825
left join transcompt3 on t1.compound_group_id = t3.group_id
where t1.detailtype_id=14519 AND t1.cat_id=11111 AND t1.exact_matching=0
group by t1.shop_id, t1.cat_id, t1.detailtype_id
having count(t3.part)=1
)
```

Comment: Let's see, ill get back to you asap... I thought this would be to straight forward and I was overlooking something

Comment: Since you get `exact_matching` from `shopdetails` table. You should update `shopdetails`. Why do you `update transcomp` ?

Comment: ur right @alex , I ve already edited the query a bit... Because there are also missing some where clauses

Comment: @DennisSeesing I was asking Simimmo :-) You didn't update any table in your post, so I have no questions to your query :-)

Comment: @Alex no lol, I ment my own query in heidisql which I based on simimmo's query. I noticed that indeed I had to update a different table and also that there were missing some statements in the where clause of his query

Comment: Right, I edited the update table, I removed the where clauses because I thought you put them to return only one row, without them you should have 3000, no?

Comment: the where clauses are mondatory, WITH the where clauses it returns 3000 rows and only these rows can be updated

Comment: btw we are quering a database with over 6.000.000 rows in tbldetailspershop and 1.700.000 rows in tbltranslationscompound.. The query from @Simimmo is way too heavy Im afraid