# Update Query Syntax When JOINing on a Query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a query that pulls all of the `contacts` that have `0` total deals in our system and `contact_status_c = Client`. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
contacts.first_name,
contacts.last_name,
contacts.phone_home,
contacts.phone_mobile,
contacts.phone_work,
contacts.primary_address_street,
contacts.primary_address_city,
contacts.primary_address_state,
contacts.primary_address_postalcode,
contacts.primary_address_country,
opportunities_cstm.stage_c,
contacts_cstm.contact_status_c,
SUM(opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Pending'
OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'AccountActive'
OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Reinstated'
OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = '%Maturity%'
OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Flagged'
OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Stalled') AS deal_count
FROM
opportunities
JOIN opportunities_cstm
ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
RIGHT JOIN contacts
ON opportunities_cstm.contact_id_c = contacts.id
JOIN contacts_cstm
ON contacts_cstm.id_c = contacts.id
WHERE
contacts.deleted = 0
AND opportunities.deleted = 0
AND contacts_cstm.contact_status_c <> 'Lost Client'
GROUP BY
contacts.id
HAVING deal_count = 0
ORDER BY
contacts.first_name ASC,
contacts.last_name ASC
```

It pulls 175 contacts. Now I'm trying to update all of the `contact_status_c` records in the `contacts_cstm` table to reflect that all 175 of these clients are listed as `Lost Clients` instead of `Client`s. Herein lies the issue.

Originally, I just tried to use a basic Update statement to do this, but because it was too broad, it updated 1881 records instead of the 175. Thus, I concluded I needed to include group by and having. Using the information provided at:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793914/using-a-having-clause-in-an-update-statement
```

(this one being the most useful) and several other forum posts and articles I managed to write this statement:

```
UPDATE
    c_1
FROM
    contacts_cstm c_1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            contacts.first_name,
            contacts.last_name,
            contacts.phone_home,
            contacts.phone_mobile,
            contacts.phone_work,
            contacts.primary_address_street,
            contacts.primary_address_city,
            contacts.primary_address_state,
            contacts.primary_address_postalcode,
            contacts.primary_address_country,
            opportunities_cstm.stage_c,
            contacts_cstm.contact_status_c,
            SUM(opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Pending'
            OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'AccountActive'
            OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Reinstated'
            OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = '%Maturity%'
            OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Flagged'
            OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Stalled') AS deal_count
        FROM
            Contacts_Cstm 
        RIGHT JOIN contacts
            ON opportunities_cstm.contact_id_c = contacts.id
        JOIN opportunities_cstm
            ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
        JOIN opportunities
            ON opportunities_cstm.id_c = opportunities.id
        WHERE
            contacts.deleted = 0
            AND opportunities.deleted = 0
            AND contacts_cstm.contact_status_c <> 'Lost Client'
        GROUP BY
            contacts.id
        HAVING 
            deal_count = 0
    ) contacts_cstm as c_2
    ON
        c_1.id_c = c_2.id_c
    SET 
        contact_status_c = 'Lost Client'
```

Unfortunately, it's throwing a "simple" syntax error:

```
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
    contacts_cstm c_1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            contacts.first_name,
            contacts.las' at line 3
```

I have looked extensively through literature and over several of the posts on here, but have been unable to figure out what's going wrong here. I have a feeling it doesn't have anything to do with the error it's throwing.

Any and all help is definitely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is `SQL Server` syntax so I won't work with MySQL.

Comment: Ah.. Makes sense. Although, admittedly, I'm not very familiar with the differences between the language. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have `MySQL` installed on my system so I can't test it, but it should be similar to the query below.  Also you don't give a table structure so I assume you have an `id` column.

```
UPDATE contacts_cstm a
JOIN (
    SELECT contacts.first_name,
        contacts.last_name,
        contacts.phone_home,
        contacts.phone_mobile,
        contacts.phone_work,
        contacts.primary_address_street,
        contacts.primary_address_city,
        contacts.primary_address_state,
        contacts.primary_address_postalcode,
        contacts.primary_address_country,
        opportunities_cstm.stage_c,
        contacts_cstm.id_c
        contacts_cstm.contact_status_c,
        SUM(opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Pending' OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'AccountActive' OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Reinstated' OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = '%Maturity%' OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Flagged' OR opportunities_cstm.stage_c = 'Stalled') AS deal_count
    FROM opportunities
    JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
    RIGHT JOIN contacts ON opportunities_cstm.contact_id_c = contacts.id
    JOIN contacts_cstm ON contacts_cstm.id_c = contacts.id
    WHERE contacts.deleted = 0 AND opportunities.deleted = 0 AND contacts_cstm.contact_status_c <> 'Lost Client'
    GROUP BY contacts.id
    HAVING deal_count = 0
) b ON b.id_c = a.id_c
SET a.contact_status_c = 'Lost Client'
```

Comment: There's no need for all the columns in the `SELECT` list of the subquery. The query optimizer will almost certainly ignore them.

Comment: @Barmar It has `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.  I don't know how it will work out so I wrap the whole query in subquery, which probably is not necessary.

Comment: You only need to select the column with the alias in the `HAVING` clause. You're not even selecting `contacts.id`, which is in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This worked like a charm! What was I missing though? Was it just the overall structure that was wrong?

Comment: @AnthonyMeyer In MySQL, when updating, you have to use the table name.  `UPDATE tableA_name JOIN tableB_name SET ...`.  In SQL Server, you do `UPDATE tableA_alias SET ... FROM tableA_name tableA_alias JOIN tableB_name tableB_alias ...`  You are definitely using SQL Server syntax since I see the table alias and the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for making the distinction! And thank you for your replies!