# SQL UPDATE with having count

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-update, having

I had this table

```
A B
1 1H
2 1H
1 1G
1 1E
```

I need update on this table column A, that take max(a) group by B having count(*) = 2.

Result will be like this:

```
A B
2 1H
2 1H
1 1G
1 1E
```

Comment: Don't store data that is calculated from other table data - you will end up with inconsistent data. Create a view instead.

Comment: This is one time script used after first data load to the table. I need set same A value to grouped B, but only if B having count = 2

Comment: Could you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793914/using-a-having-clause-in-an-update-statement    this solutions

Comment: Add some more sample data, and its new result as well. (To make the problem clearer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps?

```
update tablename t1
set A = (select max(A) from tablename t2 where t2.B = t1.B)
where B in (select B from tablename group by B having count(*) >= 2)
```

Comment: Not for every t2.b = t1.b, but only if group by b having count = 2

Comment: Thank you. This is it.

update tablename t1
set A = (select max(A) from tablename t2 where t2.B = t1.B) 
where B in (select B from tablename group by B having count(*)=2 );

Comment: Great. I'll adjust my answer to MAX().

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
update tablename t1
set A = (select count(*) from tablename t2 where t2.B = t1.B having count(*)=2)
```